# Why do classes in the Python threading module expose factory functions instead of constructors?

Tags: python

In the `threading` module, names like [RLock](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/threading.py#l111), [Semaphore](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/threading.py#l411) and [Event](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/threading.py#l541) are all factory functions, while the name of implementation classes are prefixed by underscores.

The factory functions just pass all arguments they received to the underlying constructors.

So what's the benefit of doing this?

Comment: My guess is legacy; the module is pretty old.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is it so? I'm still using Python2.7 on my machine.

Comment: `threading` was added to the library in 1998; I think Python version 1.5.1 was the first to include it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow, that's pretty old, I didn't even know about Python at that time ...

Comment: Semaphore, Event are classes in Python 3. RLock function dispatches at runtime between pure Python and C implementations (it is unclear why it doesn't do it at import time (in that case all three names would refer to classes)).

Answer (score 4):

The thread-sig archives seem to have disappeared from the Internet (*), but I'm pretty sure it's prevent you from subclassing things that aren't designed to be subclassed (you really don't want to break synchronization primitives by accident), and the module is old enough that you couldn't do that with new-style class trickery when it was added.

Also note that e.g. `RLock` has multiple implementation classes.

*) Well, I found some remnants on an FTP server in Greece, but that didn't have the original spec.

Comment: Since when does Python (and its library) try to prevent people from doing weird things?

Comment: Since always?  It's software, after all, so "prevent" means "make it a bit harder", not "make it impossible".  One obvious way to do it, etc.

Comment: Ok, but nevertheless it is usual behaviour for Python. For example, there are no private or protected class attributes, because a "grown-up" programmer doesn't need them. (At least, they say so.) Then it is unlogic and unconsequent to prevent inheriting from `RLock`. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real advantage.

Guido [added the module 1998](http://hg.python.org/cpython/diff/58d6815af002/Lib/threading.py); the first revision already includes those factory functions. Perhaps he had plans for those factory functions, perhaps he was looking at the Java implementation and copied over some idioms, perhaps he wanted to make things pluggable with a C re-implementation in the back of his head.

We can only guess, or ask Guido directly.